# MockHttpServletResponse: bodz is null for get request

Tags: spring-boot, mocking, mockito

I am using the following test

```
    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void testGetPersonById() throws Exception {
        when(this.personService.findById(any(Long.class))).thenReturn(Optional.ofNullable((person)));
        //personRepository.save(person);

        MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/api/person/{Id}", 1).
                accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).
        andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk()).
        andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", is(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.firstName", is("Raghunandan")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.lastName", is("Palakodety")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.dob", is("07.11.1987"))).andReturn();
        String response = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        //Integer id = JsonPath.parse(response).read("$.id");
        logger.info(response);
    }
```

The mockservelet response body is always null, I have no clue how to continue further. As I am trying to access the json response I am getting java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.id"

My controller contains the following

```
    @GetMapping("/person/{id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getPersonById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        String message = "";
        try {
            Optional<Person> person = personService.findById(id);
                return new ResponseEntity<Object>(person, HttpStatus.OK);
            }
        catch (Exception e){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me out how to circumvent this problem of  java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.id" while accessing in my test case?

````
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.lastName", is("Palakodety")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.dob", is("07.11.1987"))```
````

Comment: In your controller you're returning the `Optional`. You should return the `Person` instead…

Comment: It is not possible as I am using Crdurepository. Do you have any idea how I can change this?

Comment: In your controller, not in your repository…

Comment: Apart from the part that you are returning an optional which is, in my opionion, wrong unless there is a specific reason (not any i can think of tho), the place where you can be wrong is in mocking the service. ensure that : service is mocked properly and it is being injected properly while running the test